# how to put breakpoints for HTML files in web storm for an angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, debugging

I am trying to debug an angular app in web storm. My app has many .js files and also .html files. I am able to put breakpoints for .js files but do not see an option to put breakpoints for .html files. This is impeding my analysis. Please help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to debug? If you're using Chrome you can easily view the js source files and place breakpoints in your AngularJS controllers and watch the data and execution happen in real time as the page loads and you interact with it. If you're placing lots logic in the actual html page within Angular expressions, you might want to rethink your approach in what you're doing. More than likely what is being done in the page can be done in the controller before being bound to the html.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean script tags inside html files? You can do the following:

```
<script>
   var i = 0;
   debugger;
   i += 2;
   debugger;
   var j = i + 3;
</script>
```

The 'debugger' statement tells your browsers' debugger to act as a breakpoint there.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am trying to debug my entire application, I want to know the exact flow of the control. I am able to put breakpoints using the IDE and also by the way you mentioned (debugger; - wherever I need). However, if I have to put breakpoint at line no 18 in .html page, how would I do? I need this because after the navigation through my breakpoints in .js files, it is disappearing (i can step into each but i am not interested to navigate thru the other supporting files like angular.js etc). What exactly I am looking for is if my app is able to communicate well across .js and .html files

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a breakpoint in HTML. If it's a template that is rendered by angular, then you probably want to know when the template is being compiled. Read about compile (as opposed to link) and angularjs directives.

Comment: @PeterAshwell Im sorry, I completely disagree with you. To me it makes a perfect sense to put break points in the middle of HTML. I don't think Angular is powerful enough to support this feature but I put break points in the middle of HTML pages all the time on the Server Side. I use PyCharm as an IDE and Jinja2 as a templating language and you never know how awesome feature it is until you try it once.